# How to tell Kubernetes to not reschedule a pod unless it dies?

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes tends to assume apps are small/lightweight/stateless microservices which can be stopped on one node and restarted on another node with no downtime.

We have a slow starting (20min) legacy (stateful) application which, once run as a set of pod should not be rescheduled without due cause. The reason being all user sessions will be killed and the users will have to login again. There is NO way to serialize the sessions and externalize them. We want 3 instances of the pod.

Can we tell k8s not to move a pod unless absolutely necessary (i.e. it dies)?

Additional information:

- The app is a tomcat/java monolith
- Assume for the sake of argument we *would like* to run it in Kubernetes
- We do have a liveness test endpoint available

Comment: Explain more about willy nilly in this context. Also. Do you have readiness probe configured ?

Comment: Can your share your deployment YAML?

Comment: the main question could be: should this legacy app be deployed on Kubernetes?

Comment: I can't put this as an answer while the question is closed but the solution is to use a PodDisruptionBudget set to the same number of replicas as you have normally. This will prevent all voluntary evictions.

Comment: Sounds like Kubernetes could still decide to start a new instance and then kill my instance and still respect the PodDisruptionBudget. I wonder if K8S could drain the instance of sessions first and then kill it after the new instance is live?

Answer (score 1):

There is no benefit, if you tell k8s to use only one pod. That is not the "spirit" of k8s. In this case, it might be better to use a dedicated machine for your app.
But you can assign a pod to a special node - [Assigning Pods to Nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/). The should be necessary only, when special hardware requirements are needed (e.g. the AI-microservice needs a GPU, which is only on node xy).

k8s don't restart your pod for fun. It will restart it, when there is a reason (node died, app died, ...) and I never noticed a "random reschedule" in a cluster. It is hard to say, without any further information (like deployment, logs, cluster) what exactly happened to you.

And for your comment: There are different types of recreation, one of them starts a fresh instance and will kill the old one, when the startup was successfully. Look here: [Kubernetes deployment strategies](https://blog.container-solutions.com/kubernetes-deployment-strategies)

---

All points together:

1. Don't enforce a node to your app - k8s will "smart" select the node.
2. There are normally no planned reschedules in k8s.
3. k8s will recreate pods only, if there is a reason. Maybe your app didn't answer on the liveness-endpoint? Or someone/something deleting your pod?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I never said we only want one pod, in fact we want 3 instances (pods) but we cannot have a pod stopped until all sessions are drained. As I understand it Kubernetes can "defragment" nodes by reorganising pods to use resources more effectively. Is this not the case?

Comment: I don't know, if there was a feature like this, but I never noticed that (Iam working mostly with a private cloud, which has 45 nodes).